# My cards are getting overlayed. please can you show me how to arrange in row format

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
//my code here
    return(
        <div>
            {
            products.map((card,index)=>{
                return(
                    <div className="product" key={index}>
                        <div className="imgbox">
                            <img src={card.image} className="img1"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div className="specific">
                            <h6>{card.name}<br></br><span>{card.description}</span></h6>
                            <div className="price">{card.price}</div>
                                <label>Size</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>20mm</li>
                                    <li>25mm</li>
                                    <li>30mm</li>
                                </ul>
                                <form>
                                    <div className="form-group"><label>Quantity</label><br />
                                        <select>
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                            <option>5</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <button className={this.state.button ? "buttonTrue": "buttonFalse"} onClick={this.handleClick}>Add to Cart</button>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                )
                })
                }
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

export default Content;

Comment: Where is your CSS? Please reformat your question so we have the chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can do something like

```
<div className="row no-gutters">
   <Card className="col-displaySize-flexNumber" />
</div>
```

- `<Card />`  would be your element inside map function and div with row class will be outside
  ** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ will explain col-displaySize-flexNumber
  If you are using CSS only, i suggest you to read about flexbox